# Does order of inner and outer joins matter?

Tags: mysql, sql

Are there any circumstances that would cause different number of records returned from a query that includes inner joins and outer joins depending on the order of the joins?

As a simple example, could there be any difference in the resultset generated by this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
JOIN table2 on table1.id = table2.id
LEFT OUTER join table3 ON table1.id = table3.id
```

....or by this query which differ only by the 2 join conditions being swapped

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER join table3 ON table1.id = table3.id
JOIN table2 on table1.id = table2.id
```

Comment: no difference at all

Comment: In your example, they should return the same result set, although the rows and columns may be in a different order.

Answer (score 0):

For INNER JOIN order doesn't matter. But for OUTER JOIN it does.

'Table1 JOIN Table2' is same as 'Table2 JOIN Table1'

But,

'Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2' is not same as 'Table2 LEFT JOIN Table1'

Outer Joins are neither commutative nor associative. You may checkout EXPLAIN PLAN to understand the performance difference.